# How to create operator variables and lists of operators?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, operators

I want to know if it is possible to create a variable that is an operator. (Please note I only started programming Mathematica today) For example, the partial operator $\partial_x$ i.e.

```
partX = D[#,x]&
```

Ideally I would want to use it in the following way.

```
partX*(x^2)
```

Which would return 2x. This is mostly so I can store it and manipulate it and use it when I want to.

On a related note, I was wondering if I could do this with lists as well.

```
del = {D[#,x]&, D[#,y]&, D[#,z]&}
del*(xyz)
```

Which would ideally return

```
{yz,xz,xy}
```

I was wondering how this would work because I was also hoping to create operators like $\partial_x\partial_y$ by multiplying the variables for each individually i.e.

```
partXY = D[#,x]&*D[#,y]&
```

or

```
partX = D[#,x]&
partY = D[#,y]&
partXY = partX*partY
```

Please let me know if you can answer any or all of these questions. Thanks!

Comment: An easy way to do things *like* this is with `ReplaceAll`. Basically leave your terms undefined until you replace later. One thing to note, however, is that you'll need to generally use `**` instead of `*` to avoid Mathematica's automatic commutativity.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. So I just demarcate partials with `Subscript[d,x]` for example and later do `ReplaceAll[Subscript[d,x]->D[#,x]&]`? Would that work if I had something like say `Subscript[d,x]*x^2`? I assume it would then turn that expression to 2x?

Comment: Pretty much, except you'd want to start with `Subscript[d,x]@x^2`, rather than `*`. Or you could do `ReplaceAll[Subscript[d,x]**a_:>D[a,x]]` and start with `NonCommutativeMultiply`. By the way, use the back-tick, ` to get code in comments.

Comment: See also the Applications tab in the docs for [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html)

Comment: What is the non-commutative multiplication for? Also, I didn't really understand `ReplaceAll[Subscript[d,x]**a_:>D[a,x]]`, What is all the stuff in the middle? This is the code I attempted to write but it didn't work.

`k=Subscript[d,x] *x^2
ReplaceAll[Subscript[d,x]**a_:>D[a,x]] [k]`

Comment: nevermind, I understand the non-commutative part but still don't understand the other part

Comment: `Subscript[d, y]*Subscript[d, x]` becomes `Subscript[d, x]*Subscript[d, y]`. On the other hand, `Subscript[d, y] ** Subscript[d, x]` remains `Subscript[d, y] ** Subscript[d, x]`. It tells M- not to assume the operators are commutative, hence it doesn't sort the multiplication at all. The reason your example didn't work is because you'd need `k=Subscript[d,x]**x^2`. `a_` is a pattern that means: "match any single expression and assign it to `a_` for the purposes of replacement"

Comment: the way my code is written, it is a bit hard to keep derivatives at the end. Is it possible to take a term like `x*y*z` and rearrange it to be non-commutative like `x*z**y`?

Comment: Sure. `ReplaceAll` and friends can do that for you, too. I think taking some time to dive into the docs will save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: Thank you! I had just started Mathematica today so I don't even know what to search hahah

Comment: No problem. It's a massive system. If you have programming experience, as great place to start are Leonid Shifrin's answers on this site. He is a Mathematica guru. I've got a little tutorial-in-progress [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/MathematicaBasics.nb) if you want that.

Comment: I'll make sure to look into it! I have plenty of programming experience but Mathematica runs in quite a different paradigm ...